What is the best way to manage a large bush(previously bush hogged down)?
We moved to a property that was being used as a hay field but had a large garden previous to that. We find new plants all the time and I have found a row of bushes that I would like to let regrow for a privacy hedge. It’s gotten quite overgrown with grass. My question is “is it better to weed this by hand or dig up and replant? I’m also unsure of what kind of bush it is.

Pictures please!
